# APNS and continuous broadcast of messages

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

So I've been developing an instant messenger for iOS, which uses APNS for notifications when a user has no active sessions.

Currently, if the user is active, it will not send a notification, but there may be times when a message is sent, and then the user closes the app a split second after the message arrived.

This means that the user will probably miss the message, since no notification was sent. On the other hand, if a notification is sent all the time, the user will probably get a "ding dong" on the lock screen.

My question is, is sending an APNS notification along with every message "industry standard"? Do apps like whatsapp/viber do this, or do they try to play nice with APNS and only use it when there's no sessions stored?

Answer (score 0):

While I can't tell you if it's "industry standard" (though I doubt it's "nice" to spam so many notifications), I just wanted to note that you do control what is done when a notification arrives while the app is active (ie you can choose to ignore the notifications without playing the sound). So no, the user would not get "ding dong"s.

A better way than to spam APNS would probably be to mark messages as "read" after they were displayed for like 2 seconds. If the user closes the app, use the appicon badge to display the number of "unread" messages, thus preventing your split-second-app-close problem (user would see that there is 1 unread message).